# Unity doesn't receive all the information given from another software by udp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp, anylogic

My problem is that Unity doesn't read or process all the information from another software, in this case is Anylogic, how you can see in the pictures, the print of both software are not matching, I also sent the code of the UDP in Unity, if it's necessary I can also send the code of udp in Anylogic.

Print in Anylogic:

[image]

Print in Unity

[NEW UNITY DEBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fudu3.png)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
    
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEditor;
using static JSONReader;

[Serializable]
public class RealTimeItem
{
    public GameObject Object;
    public int NetID;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Target;
    public float TimeReach;
    public float TimeReachNext;
    public bool change;

    public Agente agent;
}

public class UDPClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RealTimeItem> items;

    public static UDPClient instance;
    public int portListen = 4444;
    public string ipSend = "";
    public int portSend = 5555;

    public GameObject[]  notifyObjects;
    public string messageToNotify;

    private string received = "";
    
    private UdpClient client;
    private Thread receiveThread;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    private IPAddress ipAddressSend;

    public float TimeStamp = 1;

    public bool SetData(Agente ag)
    {
        if (getObjWithID(ag.id) == null) 
            return false;

        RealTimeItem itemUse = items[GetID(ag.id)];
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(ag.id);

        GameObject obj = getObjWithID(id);

        /*
        if (ag.coordenadas.Count > (ag.coordenadas.Count - 2))
        { 
            itemUse.Position = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 2]; 
        }
        */

        itemUse.Position = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 1];
        itemUse.Target = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 1];

        itemUse.TimeReach = ag.tiempos[ag.tiempos.Count - 1];
        itemUse.TimeReachNext = ag.tiempos[ag.tiempos.Count - 1];
        itemUse.change = true;

        // Debug.LogError("Checking: " + itemUse.NetID + "|||AGID: " + ag.id);
        //  obj.transform.position = itemUse.Position;
        return true;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach(var xItem in items)
        {
            //  xItem.Object.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(xItem.Object.transform.position, xItem.Position, TimeStamp * Time.deltaTime);
            //  xItem.Object.transform.LookAt(xItem.Target);
        }
    }

    public int GetID(int SearchID)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.NetID.Equals(SearchID)) 
                return items.IndexOf(item);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public GameObject getObjWithID(int SearchID)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.NetID.Equals(SearchID)) 
                return item.Object;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Awake ()
    {
        instance = this;

        //Check if the ip address entered is valid. If not, sendMessage will broadcast to all ip addresses 
        IPAddress ip;

        if (IPAddress.TryParse (ipSend, out ip)) 
        {
            remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (ip, portSend);
        } 
        else 
        {
            remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Broadcast, portSend);
        }

        //Initialize client and thread for receiving

        client = new UdpClient (portListen);

        receiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // Check if a message has been received
        if (received != "")
        {
            //Debug.Log("UDPClient: message received \'" + received + "\'");

            // Notify each object defined in the array with the message received
            foreach (GameObject g in notifyObjects)
            {
                g.SendMessage(messageToNotify, received, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }

            // Clear message
            received = "";
        }
    }

    // Call this method to send a message from this app to ipSend using portSend
    public void SendValue (string valueToSend)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (valueToSend != "") 
            {
                // Get bytes from string
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (valueToSend);

                // Send bytes to remote client
                client.Send (data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                Debug.Log ("UDPClient: send \'" + valueToSend + "\'");

                // Clear message
                valueToSend = "";
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception err) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Error udp send : " + err.Message);
        }
    }

    // This method checks if the app receives any message
    public void ReceiveData ()
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            try 
            {
                // Bytes received
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] data = client.Receive (ref anyIP);

                // Bytes into text
                string text = "";
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (data);
    
                received = text;
                Debug.Log("UDPClient: message received \'" + received + "\'");
        
            } 
            catch (Exception err) 
            {
                Debug.Log ("Error:" + err.ToString ());
            }
        }
    }
        
    // Exit UDP client
    public void OnDisable ()
    {
        if (receiveThread != null) 
        {
            receiveThread.Abort ();
            receiveThread = null;
        }

        client.Close ();
        Debug.Log ("UDPClient: exit");
    }
}
```

So, I tried nothing at this moment, because I'm inexperienced in this area, but this was working good until I put a library thing in Anylogic, maybe that is the problem, but I´m  not sure, so, anything will be welcome, and my expected results are that all the information is processed.

*UPDATE*
In the function `ReceiveData` after `received = text;` I put `Debug.Log("UDPClient: message received \'" + received + "\'");` and deleted from function `Update`, and now the Debugs from both software are the same, now the question is, Where is the error that does not allow the updating of the data since they are read by Unity correctly.

Comment: UDP is unreliable.. also the order of packages.. maybe you rather want to switch to TCP?

Comment: @derHugo why is udp unreliable?, and the order of package how can affect? I will consider the switch to TCP.

Comment: Is this local?

Do you have any packet loss?, as @derHugo said thay aren't realiable and you don't always receive them in order, you may have to switch to tcp and if you still want to use UDP you can use some solution like darkrift, which is for free and there is discord support in there

Comment: @SajjadHayder yes, this is local, in terms of packet loss in fact, to give you an example from the images, in the Anylogic one (which is the one with the white background), it looks like for every second gives different data information for the "Worker", however, Unity receives the information of the "Worker" in seconds 1, 3 and 6, at least those are seen. And yes, I receive the information in order per seconds, I will look for the solution that you have given me for UDP, thanks.

Comment: You can use a reliable UDP .. for this however you would need to be able to also modify the sender side .. in this you include a counter into the data and request missing packages until you have them all .. not sure though why you have to stick to UDP if TCP basically already implements this for you ...(except maybe net hole punching - which doesn't seem the case here as yours is local)

Comment: @derHugo I want to stick to UDP because I already have the code implemented, and  it's to avoid changing it, but with the answers that I have received, maybe I look for the TCP codes and implementing.